# Does python have the equivalent of Perl's regex "local" variable?

Tags: python, regex, perl

While searching for a solution to a python regular expression problem I found [this page](http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide083.html) which demonstrates that [some version of] perl allows variables within regular expressions.

e.g. a perl regex *something* like:

```
^(?{ local $d=0}\((?{ $d++ }.*?\)(?d--)
```

Where variable `$d` is incremented and decremented depending on which part of the regex you're in.
[(See the link for a real example)](http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide083.html)

Is there something equivalent in python?

Note: I realize that you can achieve this goal with a real parser and a grammar, but I don't want to add another dependency to overcome this tiny problem for a script I'm writing.  And no, this script doesn't have to have [nine nines of uptime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uptime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need a grammer - pyparsing is nice (and easy)

Comment: sad. I was hoping to not install another lib.